# Accessing column data with multiple dot in column name in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, escaping

I am trying to access one column data in MySql, but the problem is that the column name consists of few dots. 
e.g the column name is

```
DATA.COM.WITH.123.VALU
```

I know its weird but that how columns are defined and I tried different ways e.g putting a dot in start of column name but it didn't work

```
SELECT column AS '.DATA.COM.WITH.123.VALU' FROM table Datacom;
```

or

```
select DATA.COM.WITH.123.VALU from Datacom;
```

or

```
select "DATA.COM.WITH.123.VALU" from Datacom;
```

but then I got this error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near '.WITH.123.VALU from Datacom' at line 1
```

if somebody give me a tip how to get column data while column name include so many dots in between . thanx for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea would probably be to avoid this issue to begin with and use column names that don't have any special characters. If this isn't possible, you can use backticks to escape column names:

```
SELECT `DATA.COM.WITH.123.VALU` FROM Datacom; 
-- Here^----------------------^
```

Comment: thanx for the tip, I tried this but it didn't work.  SELECT ^DATA.COM.WITH.123.VALU^ FROM Datacom; . .

Comment: @xee you're supposed to use ` not ^

Comment: I am getting this error now: 

druid error: SQL parse failed (org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException): Lexical error at line 1, column 8. Encountered: "`" (96), after : ""

Comment: Turns out for me the escape symbol was " not `

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks for escaping column names:

```
SELECT column AS `.DATA.COM.WITH.123.VALU`
FROM table Datacom;
```

You can access it the same way:

```
SELECT dc.`.DATA.COM.WITH.123.VALU`
FROM (SELECT column AS `.DATA.COM.WITH.123.VALU`
      FROM table Datacom
     ) dc
```

Note that the column identifier itself needs to be escaped, not the column name with the table name.

Then, ask yourself why the periods are so important.  Why not just use underscores, which do not need to be escaped?

```
SELECT column AS DATA_COM_WITH_123_VALU
FROM table Datacom;
```

Comment: thanx for the tip but backticks are not working here.

Comment: @xee . . . You should edit the question and show the version with backticks.  That is the escape character built into MySQL and I don't know how to turn it off (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: backticks works fine. thank you very much. .your and Mureinik suggestion was useful and it works perfectly fine.